# When I do a full nmap portscan on my rackspace server I find port 1984 open - "BigBrother". Is this ok?

Tags: rackspace-cloud

I'm assuming this is some sort of Rackspace management port. Am I correct?

Comment: ask rackspace would be my first suggeston.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our support team can help you determine whether this is expected for your account - http://www.rackspace.com/support/. 
Thanks!
Jeremy Wasner
Rackspace Hosting